# How to generate barcode of given text using zxing library in iphone?

Tags: iphone, zxing

I have zxing libray using that libray I wan to generate barcode of given text, How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review these links and try it yourself...

1. http://basheerad.blogspot.in/2012/04/integrating-zxing-qr-code-reader-in.html
2. http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/
3. [Managing views while integrating zxing for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263282/managing-views-while-integrating-zxing-for-iphone)
4. https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/iphone